# Using only the top mic in an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

As far as I know there are 2 mics on an iPhone. 1 is near the top next to the audio jack, and the other one is the microphone you speak into. 
The default mic seems to be the one you speak into.

How does one choose programmatically which microphone to use? I'm using Core Audio for my app.

Basically I want to use the top mic for recording. Currently when I record the bottom mic is being used. Is there a way to override the default mic setting?

I know that one can override the default speaker setting by the following.

```
UInt32 yes = YES;

AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,        sizeof(UInt32),   &yes );
```

Anything similar for microphone on an iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? Something like reducing the gain on the bottom mic would be good as well...

Comment: [Technical Q&A QA1799 AVAudioSession - Microphone Selection](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1799/_index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AVAudioSession to get available inputs.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs);

"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x14554400, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = Back>"
```

Then use one of these inputs to get availableDataSources, like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0].dataSources);

"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145afb00, ID = 1835216945; name = Bottom>",
"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b1870, ID = 1835216946; name = Front>",
"<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b3650, ID = 1835216947; name = Back>"
```

**We can see that there are actually THREE microphones on this iPhone: top front, top back, and bottom. Now you can set your preferred data source.**

```
AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0];
for (AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *source in port.dataSources) {
    if ([source.dataSourceName isEqualToString:@"Back"]) {
        [port setPreferredDataSource:source error:nil];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you
Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 4):

my 2 cents for swift 4:

```
class func test3Mics(){

        guard let inputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs else{
            return
        }
        print(inputs.debugDescription)

        for input in inputs{
            print(input.dataSources ?? "??")
        }

        // set preferred:
        let preferredPort = inputs[0]
        if let dataSources = preferredPort.dataSources{
        for source in dataSources {
                if source.dataSourceName=="Back" {
                    do {
                        try preferredPort.setPreferredDataSource(source)
                    }catch _ {
                            print("cannot set frontDataSource")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```